# Login in GitLab failed from PhpStorm

Tags: git, gitlab, phpstorm

From two weeks ago I couldn't push in commit in GitLab from PhpStorm,
it says username or password is wrong but it is correct and I can't figure it out.

Any help I will grateful for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to personal_access_tokens page:
https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens

and create new access token then copy your new personal access token and use it instead of the password.